# Can I hide a specific character (,) from the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, hide

Complete noob here. 
The CMS I'm forced to use is spitting out commas (,) on a page and I want to hide them from the viewer as they are messing up my layout.

The code (that I CANNOT edit) typically looks like this:

```
<img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> , <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> , <img class="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> ,
```

I can however wrap the above html in a div. I can also add and javascript or jquery to either the header or footer of the page. The page contains multiple instances where there are blocks of images- sometimes I might have 4 or 5 images together - all are currently being comma separated. These commas are appearing in the browser and it's these that I want to remove.

A working demo where these commas are removed would be amazing. Thanks all who read this.

Comment: wrap them in a span with class="hide" and then in css define class .hide{ opacity : 0 } or .hide{ display : none }

Comment: Hi Pete, I have indeed taken a full tour of the help centre. I think I've asked a pretty decent question that I have not seen asked or answered here. I could add my failed attempts, but as I said I'm just a beginner and I don't think my code would help anyone in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution but I think you can get the point. Just strip the commas from the contents of the div, since you said you can do that.

```
container.html().replace(/,/g, "")
```

Example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgej21oh/)

Comment: Brilliant Rafael, Thanks so much for your simple helpful reply. I think your post will prove useful for many other and not just me.